# Passing PySide object to C++

Tags: c++, pyside

I am trying to porting qimage2ndarray from PyQt to PySide. The python part of the code seems to work if I change the import from PyQt to PySide, but the SIP part

http://www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/~meine/hg/qimage2ndarray/file/0682b7bcaca3/qimageview.sip

does not. It gives the error:

```
qimageview(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'PySide.QtGui.QImage'
```

I am quite surprised by that, because the function is defined with

```
qimageview(QImage &image)
```

How do I cast a `PySide.QtGui.QImage` to an `QImage` that can be used within C++?

I never worked with SIP nor anything else than scipy.weave to embed C++ into python. Perhaps SIP is not the right way to go with PySide?!

Answer (score 0):

No, sip is not the right tool to use.

Although [sip](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/introduction.html) is a general purpose tool for creating python bindings for C/C++ libraries, it is not directly compatible with PySide, which generates its bindings using a different tool.

The PySide equivalent to sip is [shiboken](https://shiboken.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).